# How to re-add form data after preview and going back?

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage and a place to submit data. I made a preview page for this, and whenever a user clicks 'preview' he can see what it would look like. The trouble is whenever they click the back button from the preview all the data is gone. How do I avoid this and keep the data without any very complex solutions?

---

### preview.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$getTitle =  $_POST['title'];
$getEntry = $_POST['entry'];

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$getTime = date('D, M jS, o, H:i a e');

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

?>

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<head> <title>  Blog - Preview </title> </head>

<body>

    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="navPreview">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="addentry.html">Back</a><br></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <div class="main">

            <h1>Preview</h1>

            <div class="mainscroll">
                <?php
                    echo "<span>Submitted at: $getTime by $user</span><br>";
                    echo "<h2>$getTitle</h2>";
                    echo "<p>$getEntry</p><hr>";
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">x</div>

</body>
```

---

### addentry.html

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<head> <title> Blog - Add Entry </title> </head>

<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">

        <h2> Welcome.. </h2>
        <p>..add an entry below</p>

    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a><br></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add Entry</a><br></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <form id="entryForm" action="addentry.php" method="post">
            <p class="title">
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="title"><br>
            </p>
            <p class="body">
                <label>Entry:</label>
                <textarea name="entry"></textarea><br>
            </p>
            <p class = "buttons">

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function clearConfirm() {
                        var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to clear?");
                            if (confirm) {
                                document.getElementById("entryForm").reset();
                            }
                    }
                    function previewForm(action) {                                  document.getElementById('entryForm').action = action;
                        document.getElementById('entryForm').submit();
                    }                           
                </script>

                <input type="button" onclick="clearConfirm()" value="Clear" />
                <input type="button" onclick="previewForm('preview.php')" value="Preview" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add a `target="_blank"` ? It will open the preview in a new tab.

```
<input type="button" onclick="previewForm('preview.php')" value="Preview" target="_blank"/>
```

EDIT: Oups not in the form but on your preview link...
Or something like this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp

Comment: With formtarget too ? What's your webbrowser ?

Comment: formtarget too, Chrome. Does it need to be button or will my input work too?

Comment: I tried with <button> too, no result either with formtarget or target.

Comment: This worked. `<button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" onclick="previewForm('preview.php')">Preview</button>`

Comment: document.getElementById('entryForm').target = '_blank';
    document.getElementById('entryForm').submit();

EDIT: oh ok, think about the other solution ;)